# Partition by getting the previous date in the same partition

Tags: sql, hive, apache-spark-sql, hiveql

I have the following table with output including the result of my sql query that is not giving me the output I would like to see (I am doing this is in pyspark, so the hive version of sql):

Here is the query I am running (I have tried a bunch of variations of this with range/row and different preceding/following unbounded etc none of which seem to give me the output I want):

```
select id, date_1, acct_num, date_2, txn_am,
min(date_1) OVER(PARTITION BY acct_num
ORDER BY date_1 ASC RANGE BETWEEN 2 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) as lower_bound_timestamp      
from abc.def
order by acct_num, date_2
```

This is what I want the output to look (in this query I am just creating the lower_bound_timestamp column). If you notice the key thing I want is the lower_bound_timestamp
not to be necessarily the value of date_1 in the preceding row, I want it to be the 
preceding value of the date_1  (it is ordered by date asc) because if there are 
say 5 rows with the same date followed by 3 rows with the different next date, I want
those 3 next rows to have a lower_bound_timestamp of THAT previous date_1 only however my 
queries the many variants I try none of them accomplish it:

```
id        date_1     acct_num   date_2      txn_am        lower_bound_timestamp


123       2019-06-26   123      2019-06-10   10           2019-06-26
354       2019-06-26   123      2019-06-15   10           2019-06-26
357       2019-06-28   123      2019-06-15   10           2019-06-26
359       2019-06-30   123      2019-06-17   10           2019-06-28
360       2019-07-05   123      2019-06-18   10           2019-06-30
361       2019-07-05   123      2019-06-20   10           2019-06-30
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `range()`, but with numbers:

```
select id, date_1, acct_num, date_2, txn_am,
       min(date_1) over (partition by acct_num
                         order by datediff(date_1, '2000-01-01')
                         ranged between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding
                        ) as prev_date
from abc.def
order by acct_num, date_2
```

Comment: I can't do something like this because I don't have a fixed date like in your '2000-01-01' example. What would be the point of it anyway?

Comment: @mathlover . . . That converts the date to a number, so you can use `range` partitioning.   The date value doesn't matter.

Comment: @mathlover . . . That is not helpful.  You need to explain how it does not work.